# How to deal with poor, but valid questions in close vote queue?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

From time to time I fail a review audit in the close vote queue. But it is always the same type of question:

- quite poorly formatted
- -1 score (at least displayed in case of audit)
- Question is clear to me, but it could be not clear on the very first glance
- There is an already accepted answer, which completely answers the question, how I understood it.

[Here an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724672/find-special-numbers-in-excel-macro)
In my understanding it is a poor, but valid question. **Yes, I could edit it.** But most of the times I don't see the point spending time in editing questions, which are easy to answer and poorly formatted and **already answered**.

So should I just skip questions which are good enough, not to be closed, but require improvement, which I don't want to spent time on? These posts just became an review audit, because the people who flagged for closure and downvoted were just too lazy to deal with the post properly (like I am)?

**Edit:** One could argue, that a question like this, without improvement has no value for any future reader and therefore should be closed. But for what reason? *Unclear what you're asking* (the reason why it was closed) - doesn't appear a valid reason for me, as it has a correct accepted answer. So it must have been clear what the OP asked.

Comment: Strange question.  What else are you going to do when you don't want to edit and don't want to skip?  Maybe just don't bother and answer a fresh question, there are plenty.

Comment: @HansPassant I edited my question. Yes skipping would be the obvious thing to do, but I rather feel like closing it, as it has not much value, but there is no closing reason which fits. Should I just use any closing reason to get rid of the question?

Comment: We run a chatroom for close vote reviewers [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). Feel free to seek advice there by leaving a message. One of the regulars will be happy to help you out.

Comment: The current close dialog version is filled with wwww, wishy-washy weasel words.  Designed to minimize the odds that the OP will complain and making you look stoopid for using them.  If you can live with looking foolish for picking "unclear what you're asking", even though you know what he's asking, then you've got my blessing to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is indeed a very poor question. Normally if a question has been closed as *unclear what you are asking* but also has a marked answer then it couldn't have been that unclear (In other words, the unclear reason was simply the easiest to justify to close the low quality question).

However that example question only becomes clear if the OP's comment is edited into it. **Because of this you should vote to close it.** Sure you can edit it instead, but in lieu of that it should be closed - it doesn't matter if it has already been answered (it's still a poor question unless you make it better).

Comment: So as we don't have **Low quality* as close reason anymore, I just should choose *Unclear what you're asking* to get rid of the question?

Comment: Absolutely you should - because the presence of a marked answer in this case was a red herring. Even if the OP's comment is edited in it's still low quality - effectively a "do my code for me" request.